# Subsetting in R with multiple criteria

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataset as follows (in data.frame format):

```
>dataset
X Y Z Value
a c f 12
a d f 45
a c f 654
a d g 684
a c g 54
b d f 78
b c f 31
b d f 777
b c g 54 
b d g 45
```

And I have an second data.frame with criteria:

```
>criteria
X Y Z 
a c f 
b d f
```

How do I apply the second matrix to the first to get, in this example, c(654, 12, 777, 68) as a result? Most of the things I've tried end up pulling out all the lines with any of the three variables matching instead of all three.

EDIT: Fixed what the result is supposed to be

Comment: You can use `merge`. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) for more details.

Comment: Why not `c(654, 12, 777, 68)` as a result?

Comment: Paulo, you're correct. I wasn't very careful with my example apparently. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Just use `merge`:

```
merge(df1, df2)
```

If you want just the vector:

```
merge(df1, df2)[,'Value']
```

Data:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = 
'X Y Z Value
a c f 12
a d f 45
a c f 654
a d g 684
a c g 54
b d f 78
b c f 31
b d f 777
b c g 54 
b d g 45', h = T)

df2 <- read.table(text = '
X Y Z 
a c f 
b d f', h = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

adding some points on y logic :

```
do.call(paste0, criteria)
# [1] "acf" "bdf"
do.call(paste0, dataset[1:3])
# [1] "acf" "adf" "acf" "adg" "acg" "bdf" "bcf" "bdf" "bcg" "bdg"
v = do.call(paste0, dataset[1:3]) %in% do.call(paste0, criteria)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Now this logical vector is used to subset the Value column

```
dataset$Value[v]
# [1]  12 654  78 777
```

Comment: why did i get a downvote?? mind explaining that whoever did it?

Comment: Not my downvote, but this seems like a hacky way to do an inner join. I think Paulo's "just use merge" answer is spot on.

Comment: @joel.wilson "_why did i get a downvote??_" I'm not the one who downvoted it, but it's probably because code-only answers are low quality. Please edit to add some context.

Comment: @DonaldDuck do you think is the reason for downvote...i don't think so.. anyway i shall keep in mind your point too! updated my answe

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
inner_join(df1, df2) %>%
             select(Value)
```